# In Argo, what is the culture official asking about?

Tags: plot-explanation, argo

Argo has a scene where the fake film crew joins an official from the Iranian government's department of culture and art (or something like that). When the official is introduced to the director, the official asks him something about the movie, and the director answers with "no" but looks confused.

What was the culture official asking about? It sounded like he was asking if the movie was going to be a love story, but I couldn't understand much of what he was saying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The culture official asks whether the film is about a foreign bride who comes to Iran, but she doesn't understand the language or the custom so there is a misunderstanding and lapse.

To this, Bob, the "director", replies that it's not.

Comment: Thank you. Was there some underlying meaning that I am missing? Bride represents US in Iran or something?

Comment: I did not think of any underlying meaning, but now that you've said, it got me thinking :) and I don't think that his question meant anything else than a casual question.

Comment: An Iranian can only answer that. It seems this plot is similar to any Iranian movie made before the timeline in Argo.

Comment: There was a 1964 Iranian movie called "The Foreign Bride." Couldn't that be it? http://www.mopopoc.com/2012/05/foreign-bride-1964-iran.html?m=1

Answer (score 4):

he was referring to the movie [Not without my daughter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Without_My_Daughter) and asking if this Argo movie is that one.

That movie was released in 1991 and represented exaggerated bad aspects of Iran and was opposed by Iranian government and people.

**Edit:**

Although that movie hadn't existed at the time Argo happened, seems like the filmmakers wanted to mention that movie to the audience. Comments of this answer make it clearer.

Comment: The culture official was most probably not referring to exactly this movie directly, given that *Argo* is set in the 70s or so. But it is still reasonable that this particular movie was meant by the filmmakers and thus as a little side-joke on Iranian-US-relationships through movies. So while this doesn't really answer the actual question, it is a very good addition to *Incognito*'s answer (and I urge the mods removing this answer to make it a comment to *Incognito*'s answer rather than to the question itself).

Comment: If you can perhaps expand this more it would be a very viable answer, as it stands currently, it is more on that edge of possibly comment.

Comment: The problem is as Christian Rau says ..... Argo is set before Not without my daughter.  Its possible the Argo writers intended it to be a reference, but its clearly not what the character is referring to.  However your answer is clearly more interesting than just a comment.

Comment: i see... now I'm starting to wonder what it was supposed to mean that he mentioned a movie which was gonna be made 10 years later!!!

Comment: @arianoo I'd say it was meant by the makers of *Argo* as a side blow to exactly this movie, even if it wasn't made yet. So this way the question of the culture official seemed quite odd to the film team (the in-move film team) and wouldn't make much sense at that time, yet to the audience it made sense quite well and gave an interesting satirical reference to the depiction of Iran in American movies. I'd also agree with *iandotkelly* that the answer, if somehow including the points of *Incognito* (which answer the actual question of what was said) had a good potential as an individual answer.

Comment: @arianoo So while the culture official's question doesn't make much sense if seen in-universe, it has a much deeper meaning when seeing the overall theme and disregarding the rather anachronistic nature of the actual words itself. Thus your answer goes much deeper than *Incognito*'s, but it should definitely mention that the culture official is not really refering to *Not Without My Daughter* directly, but only on a meta-level.

Comment: @ChristianRau you're absolutely right. Thanks for making it all clear. I'll edit my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone is looking way too deeply into this. There was no reference to any specific movie. IT was simply the Iranian asking if this was going to be a wacky comedy that uses the differences in their cultures for the laughs...because Western movies and TV often treated the culture of Iranians as a bit backwards, to the point where moviegoers are expected to laugh AT Iran. Not at the situation.